# Youtube DL prepare filename discord bot

Tags: discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot which also has a music part. I have it working but i wanted to give the info to the user of which song it's playing. Right now I've this for the play command:

```
@commands.command()
 async def play(self,ctx,url):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
  vc = ctx.voice_client
  await ctx.send("Searching for the requested song")
    
  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    videotitle = ydl.prepare_filename(info)
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)
    await ctx.send(f"Playing {videotitle}")
```

This works but i want the output to be changed. Right now i get this:

```
MIX TECH HOUSE 2020 #8 (Camelphat, Torren Foot, Cardi B, Pax, Muus, Kevin McKay...)-RN7mbUBzUJw.m4a
```

I want the part "RN7mbUBzUJw.m4a" not to be there. does any one know what goes wrong in the ydl.prepare_filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`YoutubeDL.prepare_filename`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L620) generates a string that's a valid file name, mangling the video title if necessary and including the video ID and extension. It seems you want just the video title, so you can just do the same thing that function does manually.

The [way they get the video title](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L712) is:

```py
video_title = info_dict.get('title', info_dict.get('id', 'video'))
```

where `info_dict` is the dictionary returned by `YoutubeDL.extract_info`. So in your case

```py
videotitle = info.get('title', 'Video with ID: '+info.get('id', 'unknown'))
```

should work.

Comment: Hi @Danya02 I've tried it but it goes straight to my error message. So it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @JurjenSloetjes I made the mistake of believing the documentation -- `YoutubeDL.extract_info` returns a single dict, not a list of dicts. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Got it working, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, but saying "thanks" is seen as unnecessary here on SO -- instead, upvote answers which were helpful, and mark the one that solved your problem as the accepted answer with a checkmark.